# How to create branch in multiple gerrit projects at once

Tags: git, gerrit

I have around 200 Gerrit projects. In that 70 repositories contains prefix as (network). I need to create a new branch let's say(dev_branch) once in all 70 (network) related repositories. So locally clone them all 70 repositories then creating branch is best way or other feasible way available with git/gerrit? Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using the [Create Branch](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html#create-branch) REST API endpoint.

For example, you can create a "develpment" branch in the project "sandbox/helloword" by executing:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request PUT --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/projects/sandbox%2Fhelloworld/branches/development << EOF
{
    "revision": "INITIAL-REVISION"
}
EOF
```

INITIAL-REVISION can be a SHA number, a branch name or HEAD.

You'll need to execute the above command for each "network" repository.